# MySQL CTE function call duplicated

Tags: mysql, function, common-table-expression, amazon-aurora

I expected the function call "expensive" to be called only once, but it appears to be called  for every row in "children". Can the CTE/query be tweaked to only call the function once and have that value returned for every child row (which all have the same parent id).

The function "expensive" simply inserts into the calls table, to record how manner times it is called by the query. DETERMINISTIC applied to the function does not give the desired behaviour.

Database is Amazon Aurora MySQL 8.x.

```
set @pParentId = 2;
WITH cte AS
(
   select id, sandpit.expensive(id) as result from sandpit.parents where id = @pParentId
)
SELECT p.*, c.*, cte.result
FROM sandpit.parents p
LEFT OUTER JOIN sandpit.children c ON c.parentId = p.id
JOIN cte ON cte.id = p.id
WHERE p.id = @pParentId;
```

```
create table sandpit.parents (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into sandpit.parents (name) values ("A");
insert into sandpit.parents (name) values ("B");
insert into sandpit.parents (name) values ("C");

create table sandpit.children (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    parentId int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES sandpit.parents(id)
);

insert into sandpit.children (parentId, name) values (1, "1");
insert into sandpit.children (parentId, name) values (2, "1");
insert into sandpit.children (parentId, name) values (2, "2");
insert into sandpit.children (parentId, name) values (2, "3");
insert into sandpit.children (parentId, name) values (2, "4");
insert into sandpit.children (parentId, name) values (2, "5");

create table sandpit.calls (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parentId int NOT NULL,
    callTime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: The behaviour is the same using MySQL 8.0.35 docker image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that simply adding the **distinct** modifier to the CTE query resolves the issue. I do not understand why it is necessary, but this ever so slightly modified query resolves to only a single call of the "expensive" function.

A select statement where id = @pParentId should never be more than one call, as  pParentId is a single constant value.

```
WITH cte AS
(
   select distinct id, sandpit.expensive(id) as result from sandpit.parents where id = @pParentId
)
SELECT p.*, c.*, cte.result
FROM sandpit.parents p
LEFT OUTER JOIN sandpit.children c ON c.parentId = p.id
JOIN cte ON cte.id = p.id
WHERE p.id = @pParentId;
```

Comment: See verified MySQL bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113429

Answer (score 2):

CTEs, derived tables and views are by default merged into the outer query with some exceptions (aggregation, distinct, limit etc.). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html for details.

In order to avoid such merge, you have some options:

1. Use a NO_MERGE hint: `WITH cte AS ( ... ) SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE(cte) */ ...`
2. Turn off merging for the entire session by doing `set optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge= off'`
3. Rewrite the query to avoid merging.  For example, add `LIMIT n` where `n` is larger than the maximum size of the result set.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the documentation further explaining behaviour. I still find it surprizing that when you define a *common* table expression that the *optimizer* duplicates it for every row in the result set. I intend to do some more investigation into this and I will report back on this question if I discover anything further.

Comment: MySQL will eliminate any derived tables, CTEs, and views if possible.  This is done so the optimizer can explore more query plan alternatives.  The problem here is that functions in the select list will be called for every row of the result set, and the optimizer does not take that cost into account.

Answer (score 0):

This seems equivalent:

```
SELECT  p.*, c.*, expensive(@pParentId) as result
    FROM  sandpit.parents p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  sandpit.children c  ON c.parentId = p.id
    WHERE  p.id = @pParentId;
```

(Maybe your *real* query is more complex?)

Comment: It is equivalent to the poorly performing query, in that expensive will be called once for every row, *which is what the CTE is supposed to avoid*, but does not in MySQL, unless you trick the optimizer by adding "distinct".

Comment: @DaleOgilvie - New features (e.g., CTE) are quick to be released but take years to get optimized.